# A way to tell mathematica to not alphabetically order second derivatives

Tags: functions, evaluation

I have a frame of vector fields $E_1 ,... ,E_6$ and it's convenient for me to write $E_1(f)$ as `Dt[f,e1]` where `e1` is an undefined function. The problem is when I try to compute things of the form $E_1(E_2(f))$, mathematica thinks that `e1` and `e2` are coordinates, hence they commute. Since mathematica likes to sort all the derivatives in alphabetical order, according to it, $E_1(E_2(f))$ is the same as `Dt[f,e1,e2]` when for me it is not. Is there a way to tell mathematica to not order this or at least find undefined functions that mathematica cannot alphabetically order?

Comment: You can use a different placeholder instead of `Dt`. For instance `G[f, e2, e1]` will not be re-ordered.

Comment: hmm...why not simply write `e1[f]`? are you using any of the built-in properties of `Dt`?